# How to align image to the left, heading and p to the right below each other

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a div that has an image to the left and a title and some text floated to the right, here is how it should look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kOc6.jpg

I managed to align the image and paragraph using `flexbox`, but when I add a `h3` tag before the paragraph it stays to the left, you can see the fiddle that I have provided it should be on the top of the paragraph, how can I achieve the wrapping from the picture?

I tried using floats instead of flex, but it did not work

here is my html:

```
  <div class="sda">
                     <div class="topic-cont">
                     <img src="/assets/images/test-img.jpg" alt="test-image" class="topic-img">

                     <p class="topic-p">
                        <h3>My website name</h3>
                       asdasdaas
                       asdasdaas
                       asdasdaas
                       asdasdaas
                     </p>
                     </div>

                     <div class="topic-cont">
                         <img src="/assets/images/test-img.jpg" alt="test-image" class="topic-img">            
                         <p class="topic-p">
                           asdasdaas
                           asdasdaas
                           asdasdaas
                           asdasdaas
                         </p>
                       </div>

                       <div class="topic-cont">
                           <img src="/assets/images/test-img.jpg" alt="test-image" class="topic-img">
                           <p class="topic-p">
                             asdasdaasd
                             asdasdaasd
                             asdasdaasd
                             asdasdaasd
                           </p>
                         </div>

                 </div>
```

and my css:

```
.topic-img {
  height: 130px;
  width: 150px;
}

.topic-cont {
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

.topic-p {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.sda {
  width: 200px;
}

h6 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed your problem and added the solution. All changes are mentioned with comments in the code. You have to changes these properties in your code.
Thanks.

```css
.topic-img {
  height: 130px;
  width: 150px;
}

.topic-cont {
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 400px;  /*changed*/
  display: flex;
}

.topic-p {
  margin-top: 5px;  /*changed*/
}

.sda {
  width: 200px;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0; /*Newly Added*/
  text-align: left; /*changed*/
}

.topic-detail { /*Newly Added*/
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sda">
  <div class="topic-cont">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/mdqBxVE.jpg" title="source: imgur.com" alt="test-image" class="topic-img">

    <div class="topic-detail"> <!-- a new div is added wrapping the h3 and p element -->
      <h3>My Website Name</h3> <!-- h3 is set outside the p element -->
      <p class="topic-p">

         asdasdaas
         asdasdaas
         asdasdaas
         asdasdaas
      </p>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Happy to help you :)